# Visual Studio is formatting my CSS/LESS in the way I don't want, how to turn it off?

Tags: css, visual-studio-2013, web-essentials

Recently, my LESS file was reformatted in this way:

```
selector {
    some rules
}

    selector nested-selector {
        some other rules
    }
```

I don't want the nested rule to be indented, where can I turn it off? BTW this might be a Web Essentials thing, too, I have that extension installed. But couldn't find the corresponding settings anywhere.

Answer (score 11):

Found it. Even for LESS, the rules from CSS editor settings apply and they can be found in Tools > Options > Text Editor > CSS > Advanced. Set "Hierarchical indentation" to Off.

Comment: Appreciate you answering your own question, this was bothering the crap out of me for a solid 3-4 months before I even looked for an answer haha.